# Ignore Last Word On Each Line In A Text File?

Tags: php, html

So I have a text file that has a persons name, email message and email address on each line. I need a way to output only the name and the email message, while just ignoring the the email address on the end.

My text file looks like this.

```
Joe Hello how are you? joe@yahoo.com
Jim Whats up? jim@yahoo.com
Megan How is everyone doing? megan@yahoo.com
```

I was using a foreach loop to print out each line, but it of course keeps the email address, so how would I do this but not add the email address?

```
$messages = file('messages.txt');
foreach($messages as $message)
{
  echo $message;

}
```

Comment: Find position of a last space and get a substring.

Comment: How would I do that if the length of the email message can be different for each person?

Comment: Hint: `explode()` `array_pop()` `array_shift()`

Comment: Read my comment again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comment - find position of a last space in a string and get a substring from beginning to a found position:

```
$messages = file('messages.txt');
foreach($messages as $message)
{
    echo substr($message, 0, strrpos($message, ' ')) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Okay, seeing it made it much easier to see what you were saying.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $txt=file_get_contents("Duomenys.txt");
    $lines=explode("\n",$txt);
    for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++)
    {
     $message="";    
     $words=explode(" ",$lines[$i]);
     for($x=0;$x<(count($words)-1);$x++)
     {
      $message.=$words[$x];
     }
     echo "$message<br>";
    }
```

Or break down every line to words and echo all except the last one